# Approximating derivatives using $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In a question I plotted an approximated derivative of $\sin(x)$ at the point $\frac{\pi}{4}$. After that I plotted the absolute error in this derivative approximation. I used $\cos(x)$ as the exact solution.

My question is will the exact solution of an approximated derivative of $\sin(x)$ always be $\cos(x)$? And then if it was the other way around and I was approximating $\cos(x)$ would I use $-\sin(x)$ as its exact solution?

Comment: Yes, $\sin' x = \cos x$ and $\cos' x = -\sin x$. (These are **exact**.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$

$\frac{d}{dx}\cos x=-\sin x$

These are indeed the exact "solutions".